# Dual number division

Tags: arithmetic, infinitesimals

I was reading the [Wikipedia article on dual numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_number) and I read the first part. Then on my own I tried to find how to divide two dual numbers. I came up with: $$\frac{a+b\epsilon}{c+d\epsilon}=\frac{a+b\epsilon}{c+d\epsilon}*\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon}=\frac {a\epsilon+b*0}{c\epsilon+d*0}=\frac {a\epsilon}{c\epsilon}=\frac {a}{c}$$ but the wiki page says that it's something else. Could somebody please explain why I am wrong?

Comment: you can't divide by $\epsilon$, since it is not invertible!

Comment: Maybe you did go wrong somewhere, but don't just assume Wikipedia is right. After all, we're talking about the same reference that falsely accused John Seigenthaler Sr. of complicity in Kennedy's assassination and made up the Australian aboriginal god Jar'edo Wens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find $x+y\varepsilon$ such that
$$
a+b\varepsilon=(c+d\varepsilon)(x+y\varepsilon)
$$
that reduces to
$$
\begin{cases}
cx=a\\[6px]
dx+cy=b
\end{cases}
$$
Since
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}c & 0 \\ d & c\end{bmatrix}=c^2
$$
you know that $c+d\varepsilon$ is invertible if and only if $c\ne0$ (assuming we're over a field) and, easily,
$$
x=ac^{-1},\quad y=(bc-ad)c^{-2}
$$

If you try $ac^{-1}(c+d\varepsilon)$ you don't find $a+b\varepsilon$, do you?

Where's the error? You're doing $0/0$. If you could multiply the numerator and denominator by $\varepsilon$, you could as well multiply them by $\varepsilon^2$, just do the same twice.